# Power Outage and ArcSDE

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase

I'm working on a hostile environment. Power outages, despite our efforts to minimize them, are often here.

Yesterday we had a power outage and we had 2 ArcSDE databases working. I have two sets of connections, that are essencially equal. The only difference is the instance that the database points to.

Now, after the power outage, all connections we had pointing to our main server gets a bad login user and we cannot connect.

I can connect trought oracle using that password. So, the database is fine. My guess that the problem is the service (when I direct connect it works fine too). I need to fix the service.

Any ideas on how to do that WITHOUT running another post install?

The host OS is sadly a Windows 7 Ultimate machine. I'm in the amazon forest, so please, be kind :P

**Solution found**: deleted service. Recreated one tru command line, but it did not start. Deleted that one too and created one tru post-install. Seems to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to run the command-line `sdeservice` command to redeploy the service into the Windows services list.

See step 5, here: http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/23753, and also the output from `sdeservice -h`.

Comment: agreed. And for George get at least one of these http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uninterruptible_power_supply (UPS) it will save the hours by maintaining your servers uptime and control any spikes of power surges. (from experience)

Comment: i know guys. shame on my. I already "demmanded" a UPS ;)